# MySQL error when executing statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a relatively new programmer  and I'm creating a basic mysql database for class.

I need some help with an error message that I can't seem to solve.

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')
    FOREIGN KEY(team_id)
        REFERENCES team(id)     
)' at line 8
```

My code:

```
  CREATE TABLE cyclist (
        cyclist_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        team_id INT,
        firstname VARCHAR(50),
        lastname VARCHAR(50),
        Gender VARCHAR(50),
        Age INT,
        PRIMARY KEY(cyclist_id,)
        FOREIGN KEY(team_id)
                REFERENCES team(id)
);

CREATE TABLE team (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        team_name VARCHAR(50),
        main_colour VARCHAR(50),
        year_established VARCHAR(50),
        sponsor VARCHAR(50),
        budget INT,
        PRIMARY KEY(team_id),
        FOREIGN KEY(bike_brand)
        );

CREATE TABLE race (
        race_name VARCHAR(50),
        team_capacity INT,
        prize_money INT,
        main_sponsor VARCHAR(50),
                PRIMARY KEY(race_name)
);

CREATE TABLE bikes (
        bike_brand VARCHAR(50),
        cost INT,
        colour VARCHAR(50),]
);
```

Could someone please shed some light on this?

Thank you!

Comment: You're trying to make a foreign key relationship before you made the table  `team`

Comment: its all messed up. Theres many syntax errors. undefined columns, and not in order.

Comment: For example, when creating the TEAM table, you are defining a primary key that does not exist! Redo this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PRIMARY KEY(cyclist_id,)`

Remove the comma and put it after=> `PRIMARY KEY(cyclist_id),`

Comment: i admit, you were the quicker one

Comment: ThinkTank. You So Awesome.

Comment: what about Daan's comment? foreign key to non-existent table?

Comment: Yes, right. The good order is `bikes` / `team` / `cyclist` / `race`

Comment: Thanks, odd how I couldn't spot that typo. However I totally understand the logic behind why the order is incorrect, I will redo it. Thank you :)